# SmartGWT find element by id

Tags: dom, smartgwt

I want to embedded some smartgwt in a legacy-html-file ( can't change that ).
Now I know that I can just say

```
BaseWidget.setHtmlElement(<element>)
```

The problem is finding the , it has a unique id, but the only thing I found that looks at the entire structure is

```
DOM.getElementById(<id>)
```

But this is GWT and not SmartGWT, isn't there a way to do this only with SmartGWT?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using GWT's [DOM.getElementById()](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/DOM.html#getElementById%28java.lang.String%29) method is fine.  SmartGWT extends GWT.  For core operations such as retrieving an element by ID, SmartGWT uses the GWT APIs because otherwise SmartGWT would just be duplicating functionality in GWT.

DOM.getElementById() is a wrapper around GWT's [Document.getElementById()](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/dom/client/Document.html#getElementById%28java.lang.String%29) method. SmartGWT's Showcase calls Document.getElementById() to hide the "Loading" message:
https://code.google.com/p/smartgwt/source/browse/trunk/samples/showcase/src/com/smartgwt/sample/showcase/client/Showcase.java?r=2900#707